# How to prevent cyclic relation between keys on postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, unique

There's a table called `consists_of` which relates products categories hierarchy.

```
CREATE TABLE consists_of(
    super_name VARCHAR(80),
    sub_name VARCHAR(80),
    UNIQUE(super_name, sub_name),
    PRIMARY KEY(sub_name),
    FOREIGN KEY(sub_name) REFERENCES category(name),
    FOREIGN KEY(super_name) REFERENCES category(name),
    CHECK (sub_name <> super_name)
);
```

How can I prevent a cyclic relationship, for example:

`INSERT INTO consists_of values ('Cheese', 'Cheddar')`

`INSERT INTO consists_of values ('Cheddar', 'Cheese')`

Comment: A trigger might be a little expensive as far as performance, but assuming it's OK for a sub_name and a super_name to be the same sometimes, it's hard to see any way to prevent this with a constraint, so I'd say a trigger is the most reliable way. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: I would not use `VARCHAR(80)` as keys. It will cause bulky indexes.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the second `INSERT` statement, this index would be sufficient:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON consists_of (
   least(super_name, sub_name),
   greatest(super_name, sub_name)
);
```

But that won't prevent cycles of three or more entries.

One thing I could imagine is to have a level with each category. Then you can enforce that the level of the `sub_name` must be lower than the level of `super_name`.